# How can I tell when a question was posted on the Recent Questions chat ticker feed?

Tags: support, chat, feed

I'm pretty sure I saw a question on our ticker feed today and I would like to check at what time it was published by the feed.

The closest I got to an answer was by checking the [Feeds chat user's recent tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds?tab=recent), but I think it had been too long so it doesn't show anymore.

Is there a timestamp archive for this feed somwehere? It seems to me like there was a gap in time between when I saw the question on the main page and when I saw it on the feed.

It was suggested in the comment to look for the title of the post in the chat room. While the search results returned no message found, I could see the feeds icon with the title of the post. When I click on it, I get some XML, in which the only timestamp is  and shows the current time. I don't see anything that indicates the original timestamp.

The reason I'm asking: the question got flagged as spam and invalidated during review. I'm pretty sure it appeared in the feed *after* this happened and that doesn't seem like a desirable feature. I wanted to be sure about the order events happened before bringing it up as a bug.

Comment: You should be able to search for the name of the post in the chat room. If the name changed before it was posted then you may need to try whatever it was edited to. Alternately you can search for the posters username.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Searching by the title returns "No messages found" but there is a feeds icon with the question right at the bottom and I can see a timestamp in the XML, except it seems to indicate the current time and not the time it was posted on the feed.

Comment: Do know that the [Recent tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds?tab=recent&page=2) does support paging but only if you fiddle with the page number in the url. So if it is not weeks back you might get there by looking over 2, 3 or 4 pages.

Comment: Wait, the *ticker feed*? These don't end up on the transcript... they wouldn't be searchable. hmm...  @Peilonrayz I'd search for the question ID, not the title; the actual oneboxed chat message is just a link (the full URL), and the title is URL-encoded. Searching for the ID is more reliable.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I know the other two work but wasn't sure if the ID worked. Good to know :)

Comment: You could try subscribing to the RSS feed with, say, Outlook -- that should bring a number of relatively-recent items, and then you can use Outlook's (or whatever your RSS client is) search functionality to look for it. Ticker feed items don't end up in the chat transcript, so they're not searchable AFAIK.